# How does the onreadystatechange function work?

Tags: ajax

Question:

Does the onreadystatechange update the 'myDiv' tag when the information is changed. Or does a click to the button have to be made. What I am asking is the onreadystatechange is that a user built in function which can be changed or is this a function that has been built by the user every time an AJax call is made.

Code:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  // <-----  Question here.
  {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
  }
 }

  ....

  xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

HTML:

```
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It runs when the state of the HTTP request / response that the XMLHttpRequest is processing changes.

Those states are:

> 0 UNSENT  open() has not been called yet.
>  1   OPENED  send() has not
>   been called yet.
>  2    HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and
>   headers and status are available.
>  3   LOADING Downloading;
>   responseText holds partial data.
>  4    DONE     The operation is
>   complete.

With the way your code is written, you have to click the button to send the request.